# Jackson XML - Deserialize from specific node

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm new to Jackson XML and I would like to do the following:

1. Here is the XML I'd like to convert to Java DTO:

   ```
    <s:Envelope
        xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Body>
            <cotacaoTaxaCambioResponse
                xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <cotacaoTaxaCambioResult
                    xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Exchange"
                    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <a:TaxasCambio>
                        <a:CotacaoTaxaCambio>
                            <a:CLIENTEC>0</a:CLIENTEC>
                            <a:CLIENTEV>0</a:CLIENTEV>
                            <a:COMERCIALC>0</a:COMERCIALC>
                            <a:COMERCIALV>30</a:COMERCIALV>
                            <a:DATA>2021-12-15T00:00:00</a:DATA>
                            <a:HORARIO>1027</a:HORARIO>
                            <a:MOEDA>978</a:MOEDA>
                            <a:PARIDADEC>1</a:PARIDADEC>
                            <a:PARIDADEV>1</a:PARIDADEV>
                            <a:TURISMOC>0</a:TURISMOC>
                            <a:TURISMOV>30</a:TURISMOV>
                        </a:CotacaoTaxaCambio>
                    </a:TaxasCambio>
                    <a:serviceStatus>
                        <a:CODRETORNO>0</a:CODRETORNO>
                        <a:MENSAGEM>Sucesso</a:MENSAGEM>
                        <a:MENSAGEMEN>OK</a:MENSAGEMEN>
                        <a:NRREFERENCE>0</a:NRREFERENCE>
                    </a:serviceStatus>
                </cotacaoTaxaCambioResult>
            </cotacaoTaxaCambioResponse>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
   ```
2. Info I need is attributes of a:CotacaoTaxaCambio node.
3. Created this DTO

   ```
        @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "a:CotacaoTaxaCambio")
        public class CotacaoResDTO {

            @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "a:DATA")
            private String data;

            @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "a:HORARIO")
            private String hora;

            @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "a:MOEDA")
            private String codMoeda;

            @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "a:COMERCIALV")
            private Double valorComercial;

            @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "a:TURISMOV")
            private Double valorTurismo;
        }
   ```
4. If I set this subset as input, it does work:

   ```
                <a:CotacaoTaxaCambio>
                    <a:CLIENTEC>0</a:CLIENTEC>
                    <a:CLIENTEV>0</a:CLIENTEV>
                    <a:COMERCIALC>0</a:COMERCIALC>
                    <a:COMERCIALV>30</a:COMERCIALV>
                    <a:DATA>2021-12-15T00:00:00</a:DATA>
                    <a:HORARIO>1027</a:HORARIO>
                    <a:MOEDA>978</a:MOEDA>
                    <a:PARIDADEC>1</a:PARIDADEC>
                    <a:PARIDADEV>1</a:PARIDADEV>
                    <a:TURISMOC>0</a:TURISMOC>
                    <a:TURISMOV>30</a:TURISMOV>
                </a:CotacaoTaxaCambio>
   ```

But it doesn't deserialize if I set full xml as input.

Is there any configuration or anotation that I can use to archieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment the jackson library does not support directly the [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) protocol, but you can read the part you are interested with the [`XMLStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) class directly pointing the involved tag:

```
XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader sr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(xml));
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
sr.nextTag();
while (!sr.getLocalName().equals("CotacaoTaxaCambio")) {
   sr.nextTag();
}
CotacaoResDTO value = mapper.readValue(sr, CotacaoResDTO.class);
sr.close();
```

You have to modify also your `CotacaoResDTO` class ignoring the unknown properties :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CotacaoResDTO {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DATA")
    private String data;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "HORARIO")
    private String hora;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MOEDA")
    private String codMoeda;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "COMERCIALV")
    private Double valorComercial;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "TURISMOV")
    private Double valorTurismo;
}
```

Comment: Great! It works, in the end what I did was to convert XML to JSON to navigate using JsonNode, it was an intermediate solution since I didn´t find any other before your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @EmilioNumazaki You are welcome :-) , yes it is exactly your solution without the conversion to json.